# Websolr, solr search, Heroku, and sunspot [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, solr

So I have a question. I am currently on my development machine using the Sunspot gem for searching through my Rails applications records which is really nice since it does full text searching through articles (which is a feature I really want), but the bad thing is that my app is hosted on Heroku which requires the websolr addon to get the solr server to work with their system which costs $20/month. I, being the super broke college student that I am, am now looking for a workaround to this hosting cost. Does anyone know of any? I know Solr is just a server, so I could potentially host it somewhere else and just run my solr instance through that host but I don't really know how to do that (and how to integrate it with Heroku). Has anyone got any experience with this? If this seems to difficult, does anyone have alternative full text searching options with Heroku (that are free/cheap)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku has a [guide on available full-text search options](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/full-text-search) and it includes a how-to [running your own Solr server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/full-text-search#run-your-own-solr-server).

Amazon Web Services has a [free usage tier](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) so that option should not cost you anything, at least not for the first year.

Comment: Thanks for the guides! Great suggestion! I ended up getting a EC2 server up and running but I had problems configuring a bunch of things working with my application so we ended up just going with ElasticSearch since they have a Heroku addon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can spin up a machine on Amazon EC2 and install solr on it. It starts somewhere around $10 / month. Just make sure to use the same datacenter as Heroku, which I believe is the east coast one.

Comment: Why is using same datacenter as Heroku important?